# I cannot display custom posts in custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy

I have a problem with display posts in custom taxonomy. I created custom post type `m_product` and custom taxonomy for this post type `m_product_category`. I created file in main theme folder named `taxonomy-m_product_category.php` and maked html for it:

```
protectFile();

get_header();
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    print_r($wp_query);
    ?>
    <div class="top-bg" style="background-image: url(<?php echo THEME_IMAGES_URI; ?>/ronney-produkty-akcesoria-salon-fryzjerski-str-kategorie-produktow-tlo-01.jpg)"></div>
    <?php
    echo do_shortcode('[meetProducts]');
        if (have_posts()) {
            ?>
            <div class="container py-5">
                <div class="row" id="products-list">
                    <?php
                        while (have_posts()) {
                            the_post();
                            $subtitle = get_field('m_product_subtitle');
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3 mb-3">
                                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="product-box d-block" rel="noopener">
                                    <?php
                                        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', ['class' => 'd-block mx-auto img-fluid']);
                                        }
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="text-center mt-3 product-box-title">
                                        <?php
                                            the_title();

                                            if ($subtitle) {
                                                ?>
                                                <div class="product-box-subtitle">
                                                    <?php echo sanitize_text_field($subtitle); ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                        ?>

                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php
                    if ($paged < $wp_query->max_num_pages) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="text-center mt-4">
                            <button type="button" class="load-more-products btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-next-page="<?php echo esc_attr($paged + 1); ?>" data-max-page="<?php echo esc_attr($wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>">Wczytaj więcej</button>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            echo 'test';
        }
    echo do_shortcode('[meetProducts]');
get_footer();
```

But when i go to the custom taxonomy page, can't display posts in while loop, i mean is nothing to see. I didn't make any functions which should change some queries for taxonomies. Archive working properly, i don't have set public to false or something for register taxonomy, I will show you register taxonomy code:

```
// Protect file
protectFile();

function custom_taxonomy_m_product_category() {
    register_taxonomy('m_product_category', ['m_product'], [
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'cat-slug'
        ],
    ]);
}

add_action('init', 'custom_taxonomy_m_product_category', 0);
```

I rewrited link in settings but this doesn't help. I don't have idea why this isn't working, could someone give me advice? Thanks!

//Edit:
Here is a code for register custom_post_type:

```
function custom_post_type_m_product() {    
    $args = [
        'label'               => __('Produkty'),
        'description'         => __('Produkty'),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => [
            'title',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt'
        ],
        'taxonomies' => [
            'm_product_category',
            'm_product_color'
        ],
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 6,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'rewrite'             => [
            'slug' => 'produkty'
        ],
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-cart'
    ];

    register_post_type('m_product', $args);

}

add_action('init', 'custom_post_type_m_product', 0);
```

//Edit2:

I found solution with community help, iI had set `exclude_from_search` for custom post type to `true`. Thanks for your patience, cheers!

Comment: Have you tried **'has_archive' => true** ?

Comment: @PratikPatel Hi, yes, you can check post, i edited it, i have set has_archive to true.

Comment: @PratikPatel Love you dude, i found a problem, "exclude_from_search" is set to true...

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
function custom_taxonomy_m_product_category() {
        register_taxonomy('m_product_category', ['m_product'], [
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => **false**,
            'query_var' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'cat-slug', 'with_front' => true ],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Solution is in the main thread.